# emqttd not getting all messages in same topic when subscriber application is down

Tags: persistence, mqtt, emq

Only receiving last retained message when subscriber application restarted.

OS: Windows
EMQ Broker version : 2.3.10
Eclipse paho

When I am publishing 10 messages on same topic, during that time for some reason subscriber application crashed, after sometime sub application restarted, I am getting only last retaining message only and losing all other data which is big problem.

I am putting Retained flag is true , clean session flag as false and Qos as 1 on both pub and sub.

can some one help on this.
Am I missing any configuration or Erlang broker behaves like getting only last retaining message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the MQTT broker will only hold the **last** message published to a topic with the retained flag for a given topic. Retained messages are not related to the queuing of high QOS messages for offline clients. For more details on retained messages I suggest you look at [this](https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-8-retained-messages/) post from HiveMQ

As for queuing messages for an offline client you need to meet all of the following points.

1. The clean session flag must be set to `false`
2. The client ID must remain the same across connections
3. The message must be published with a QOS > 0
4. The client must subscribe to the topic with a QOS > 0

For more details about persistence and queued messages look at [this](https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-7-persistent-session-queuing-messages/) other HiveMQ post.

Comment: Thanks hadillb, I missed the same client id has to be in while doing the resubscribing.